# Pushing to Heroku - ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation "users" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm really frustrated right now.

I have my working rails application on local and want to deploy it to Heroku. So far so good.

Whenever I try to push my code to Heroku it spits the error that no tables were found. I did try to run heroku run rails db:migrate db:drop db:reset or whatever several times without any success at all.

```
development:
  <<: *default
  database: postgres
  encoding: utf8


# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  adapter: postgresql
  database: fortest

production:
  <<: *default
  adapter: postgresql
  url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
```

All of my tables and migrations are working fine on my local machine, problem is that I need to run those migrations on Heroku to create my database tables, but somehow can't because it fails when my precompile assets start.

```
    Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
remote:        LINE 8:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
remote:                                                  ^
remote:        :               SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
remote:                             pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod,
remote:                             c.collname, col_description(a.attrelid, a.attnum) AS comment
remote:                        FROM pg_attribute a
remote:                        LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
remote:                        LEFT JOIN pg_type t ON a.atttypid = t.oid
remote:                        LEFT JOIN pg_collation c ON a.attcollation = c.oid AND a.attcollation <> t.typcollation
remote:                       WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
remote:                         AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
remote:                       ORDER BY a.attnum
```

Edit:

In my heroku logs it says Build failed -- check your build logs and in my buid logs everything works until it comes to this path:

```
 Bundle completed (32.92s)
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
-----> Installing node-v8.10.0-linux-x64
-----> Detecting rake tasks
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       rake aborted!
       ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
       LINE 8:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
```

Update:

```
Rake::Task["assets:precompile"].clear
namespace :assets do
  task 'precompile' do
    puts "Not pre-compiling assets..."
  end
end
```

With this snippet I was able to atleast push my files to heroku. However, I still have problems with all the db:migrate db:reset functions. 
db:migrate appears to have the same error.

```
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
LINE 8:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass (...)
```

db:create somehow throws me this error

```
FATAL:  permission denied for database "postgres"
DETAIL:  User does not have CONNECT privilege.
```

I see all of the data (username, password, adapter, database, port, host) and they're all fine.

Comment: what version of ruby & rails are you using? Which heroku buildpack? Which heroku stack?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What's happening here is that you most likely have a `devise_for :users` in your `routes.rb` file, which is causing Rails to look for the `Users` table when it boots up, but as you haven't run your migrations yet the table can't be found.

Comment out the `devise_for` in your `routes.rb` and push to Heroku - the migrations will run, then uncomment the `devise_for` and push again.

In general it's better to have created the `Users` table first, then add devise to the model in another, later step.

Answer (score 6):

How about

`$ git push heroku`
`$ heroku run rake db:migrate`

and then another `push` to kick the asset precompile again.

Comment: No, results in the same error.

If i try to run $ heroku run rake db:migrate it says no rakefile was found and if I try to push to heroku -- remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.

Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist

Comment: mhm maybe `heroku run rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production` Edit: oh well since there is no rakefile I guess there are no files.. Anything else before the asset pipeline error in `heroku logs`

Comment: I added that part to my question, but there weren't any other errors.

Comment: check this out. its written for rails 3 but maybe its still valid.
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline#troubleshooting